# Memcached and miss rate / check if key exists

Tags: php, memcached

Can high misses number in memcached caused any problems? Memcached don't have function for check if key exists and I need to set key with 300s expiry time. This key will not be updated until expire. My code looks like this:

```
$data=$cache->get($cache_key);
if(!$data) {
    //load from db here
    $cache->set($cache_key, $data);
}
```

It works fine, but I have very high load of traffic (over 100k online in peak). In db is data changed more frequently but on web is 5min delay ok, this is why I not update cache if db is updated and set new after expiry time.

But my question is, can I worry about misses, miss/rate? I store about 20k keys in memcached, so I can get 20k miss per 5minutes. For my data, this is ok, but what for system/server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about cache misses. I have seen memcached handle 200k ops/sec and it can actually handle more than that. 20K gets/5 min is only 67 ops/sec and that i very low for a memcached server.

Comment: 20k/5min is Misses, Hits are 5k/s